# Cut file by phrase in ubuntu terminal

Tags: html, ubuntu, terminal, grep

I downloaded some website pages with wget utility, but html pages contain too much information which is not needed. I want files to contain only text before 
`</article>` tag. I suspect that it is possible to do it with grep command, but which parameters do I need? And how to apply such command to all files in a dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the script

```
for i in *.htm; do (cat $i | grep -i "</article>" -B 9999) > $i; done;
```